# Advanced selenium webdriver tutorial/course

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, self-education

Is there an online advanced/intermediate tutorial on Selenium Webdriver. Preferably using Java. I've searched a lot but could not find such a course/tutorial. Almost 99% are very basic, and I would like to do more advanced testing with Selenium Webdriver.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Some good Selenium tutorial for beginner/Intermediate/Advance are given below :

1 - [ToolsQA](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-introduction/)

2 - [Guru99](http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html)

Comment: ToolsQA is great. I often check for new stuff there and learn a lot from this site.

Comment: Yep and Guru 99 is also providing advance stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for below mentioned links too, they contain good stuff for Intermediate and Advance level:

1. [Selenium Easy](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-webdriver-tutorials)
2. [SoftwareTestingHelp](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-tutorial-1/) *(I myself use this link as it explains concept in a very good manner)*

If you need videos for learning Advance Selenium then you can go for [QTPSelenium](http://www.qtpselenium.com/)
it's not free but very good stuff ***(if you require this)***

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked on youtube.

There are enormous resources out there on various topics.

I can share one link here about how to create and use xpath locators for simulating actions on the web elements.

https://youtu.be/vcT4Ic5pbEA
https://youtu.be/3crs-xBnkxc

Comment: This doesn't really say anything about what the linked videos do. You need to edit your answer to give more information about the content of the videos.