# Interesting Selenium projects?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I just finished my third selenium hobby project. The program that I have done was quite big and took a long time, with a lot of multithreading and coding. The program is basically a "cheap flights" program, where you pick a place you want to go (Hawaii for example), and when (2015-12-02 to 2015-01-01). The program then goes to 20-30 different airline companies and returns the cheapest or/and the fastest tickets.

This was very fun and I learned **A LOT**. Do you guys have any tips on more fun projects/programs you can do with selenium? Maybe anything fun that you have done with Selenium, beside test case automation?

Comment: Please have a look : http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15061/daily-tasks-anything-fun-challenging-to-automate-with-selenium/15069#15069

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced selenium webdriver tutorial/course](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14018/advanced-selenium-webdriver-tutorial-course)

Comment: Unfortunately, this question isn't exactly answerable. A generic "hey, got any tips" post doesn't jive with the Stack Exchange format. I don't mean to discourage you in your journey to learn Selenium - the more the merrier!! But this question as it stands isn't a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

A Few Challenging Things I have done in the past year:

- WordPress admin can be a PITA because the IDs are dynamic.
- Sign Up for some account using Mailinator and/or Gmail to verify the email
  address.
- Use a Unix Time Stamp to come up with a unique username.
- Use runScript to do something, like re-size the browser window to
  test responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something Stocks/Shares related.  The dynamic nature of the values give you a good deal of scope for asserts as does the relevant news items associated with a share.  Maybe checking the relevance of those articles?  You could then expand into additional features like verifying graph data and RNS.

The combination of dynamic data and "fuzzy" news associations could make an interesting (but not easy!) project